# TypeError while using ast

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to read my dictionary(in my file) using `ast`

```
import ast
import os

class just_a_class():
    def __init__(self, file,):
        self.file = file()
        self.read_file = open(self.file,'r+')

    def read_file(self):
        dict = ast.literal_eval(self.read_file.read())
        return 'Input: \n\n {}'.format(dict)

the_class = just_a_class("dict.txt")
print(the_class.self.read_file())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Barış/Desktop/Onemli_Programlarim/Connection_PL/conn.py", line      13, in <module>
the_class = just_a_class("dict.txt")
File "c:/Users/Barış/Desktop/Onemli_Programlarim/Connection_PL/conn.py", line 6, in __init__
self.file = file()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: `self.file = file()` remove the parentheses there, `file` is a `str` and you shouldn't be calling it

Comment: and also it's better to close the file you opened after you're done with it, and it is better not to give a name to a variable that clashes with Python's built-ins, i.e., `dict` here (syntax highlighter is also helpful for that...)

Comment: I think the answer is clear in the Error traceback itself - "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", at line 6. You are trying to call a string (file) as a function (file()). As mentioned by @Altareos, you need to replace it with self.file = file

Comment: Minor side-note: You don't want mode `"r+"` here. You read from the file, you never write to it, so opening the file for both reading and writing is wasteful and risks misbehavior, as a file opened with the intent to read it can now be written too by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is similar to what is used in the question. I've tried
to improve the readability by using common techniques and conventions,
such as using `fname` for the filename, instead of `file`, using a
context manager to open (and auto-close) the file, and capitalization
for class names. Also changed the flags to the `open()` call to be "r"
instead of "r+", as suggested by ShadowRanger.

```
import ast

class Just_a_class():
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
    def read_file(self):
        with open(self.fname, 'r') as f:
            dict = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
        return 'Input: \n\n {}'.format(dict)

the_class = Just_a_class("dict.txt")
print(the_class.read_file())
# {'a': 5, 'b': 'hello'}
```

Comment: While this technically fixes the code, it kinda skips over why it was broken in the first place, while making other changes that make it unclear what the actual problem (as opposed to poor style/design) was in the original code.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes, I agree with your conclusion, but I am unclear on how to describe all the reasons behind the fixes. I thought I would try to summarize it, then show working code that kind of captures the major theme in the original code. Thanks for the tip on 'r+'; I didn't spot that one.